# Easy way to check what files are missing

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, software-rec, file-transfer, file-management

I have 2 hard drives, I copied everything from one hard drive to a fresh drive, but some files didn't copy as they were corrupted. Is there an easy way to check what files from one hard drive are not on another?

Comment: In my view, you should look into using `rsync`, and I think that `rsync --update --list-only` should do the trick, but I'm not sure. Either way, `rsync` does an awesome job. You may also want to look at [rsyncbackup.vbs](http://www.heise.de/download/rsyncbackup.vbs.html) which some professionals created for free use because analysed commercial solutions were not satisfactory.

Comment: yea any of the sync softwares that have "compare" routines , windiff (microsoft) is really old simple small program that does compares, first scan takes forever, but learning how to use it one can re-scan, and copy what is different/wrong.  Not made for mass file copying , more for syncing programing parts and pieces in a folder sub-folder set, but it works fine for it, given the time, and is checking every bit :-) of the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
robocopy sourcedriveletter: destinationdriveletter: /MIR /LOG:logfilename.txt /TEE /L
```

**Robocopy is a command-line tool built into windows.** You can check the options by opening a cmd prompt (for this purpose, probably as admin I suppose) and typing `robocopy /?` or `robocopy /? > %USERPROFILE%\desktop\robocopyoptions.txt` if you want a text file version of the help doc.

In my sample above, `/MIR` means "mirror" and it duplicates "source" in "destination," and deletes anything in "destination" that is not in "source."

`/log:` logs to a file, `/TEE` outputs to the console as well as the logfile.

**The final command `/L` sets it to list only, and will not actually copy or delete files.**

The log will very clearly show you which files in the source do not exist in the destination.

Of course, I strongly urge you to examine the help docs first to ensure my example is correct.

Comment: Thanks @Yorik this worked with the exact command line that you put at the top, but I did check just in case, accepted

Answer (score 2):

**feedback from OP: excel method did not work for him, Matlab method is untested**
I have a very inelegant solution, but I think it does the job (assuming your have excel). It only works if the number of filenames fit in excel. (excel has a limited Max number of rows: 1,048,576).

Go to cmd (I'm assuming you are on windows). Change directory to the first drive. Type:

```
dir /s/b/o:gn > drive1.txt
```

Do the same for the second drive, but change the name of the txt file.

I took the cmd line from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447503/how-to-get-a-list-of-sub-folders-and-their-files-ordered-by-folder-names .

Copy both outputs in excel(assuming 2007 or newer). The easiest option I know of is the following:

- Select the columns that contain the cmd outputs.
- On the data tab in the Sort & Filter group, click Advanced.
- In the Advanced Filter dialog box, do one of the following:

  - To filter the range of cells or table in place, click Filter the list, in-place.
  - To copy the results of the filter to another location, do the following:

    - Click Copy to another location.
    - In the Copy to box, enter a cell reference.
- Alternatively, click Collapse Dialog Button image to temporarily hide the dialog box, select a cell on the worksheet, and then press Expand Dialog Button image.
- Select the Unique records only check box, and click OK.
- The unique values from the selected range are copied to the new location. The original data is not affected.

This way you should have a list of all the unique filenames, which is the Same as a list of all the filenames that weren't copied.

The excel procedure was in the end taken from: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-d6549cf0-357a-4acf-9df5-ca507915b704#bmfilter_for_unique_values

Alternatively you could use the cmd command in Matlab.

The command in Matlab could be:

```
DosCommand=sprintf('%s %s','dir /    B',directory);
    [status, cmdout]=dos(DosCommand);
end
Filenames = strread(cmdout,'%s');
```

Then execute:

```
NonCopiedFilenames = 

A(sum(bsxfun(@eq, A(:), A(:).'))==1);
```

The unique values trick was copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236914/how-to-find-a-unique-value-in-a-matrix-by-using-matlab

Comment: If you don't have Excel there are [free alternatives](http://www.openoffice.org/)

Comment: @BramMooij Sorry the excel method didnt work, I have thousands of rows of files and it crashes excel every time even with my good computer running on realtime

Comment: Too bad. Is the number over 1,048,576? In that case it makes some sense since that is the limit of the number of rows in excel. In any case, I will add this limit to my suggested answer. Glad you found another solution though.